# How to pass a specific value from a two-dimensional array to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So, here's my problem. I've got a two-dimensional int array all filled with values. I've got a function that accepts an int as a parameter. How would I get the function to pull a specific value from the array to use as its parameter? Is it as simple as using "array[x][y]" as my parameter or do I have to do anything special with the function definition?

Comment: Did you try it first? It is as simple as using array[x][y] as your parameter.

Comment: I hadn't tried it, mainly because I don't have the values ready to put into the array yet. I suppose I should've made a test on a smaller scale first. In any case, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you rewrite the function signature, as it will take 2 integer parameters? Then you can call it with x and y?

Comment: I could, but I wasn't sure about the array's scope and didn't particularly want to go to the trouble of making it dynamic. As I said above, I should've tested it first.

Answer (score 1):

`array[x][y]` is a correct way to access array value.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[4][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}};

    foo(a[1][0]); // print 2
    foo(a[2][1]); // print 5

    return 0;
}
```